# Laravel query builder not saving data in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables products and labels, and the relationship between them is belongsToMany, I want to assign a label to the product after creating it, so I'm using Laravel observer.
Here my code

```
 public function created(Product $product)
 {
  $label = Label::where('as_new', true)->first();
  DB::table("products_labels")
   ->insert([
    'product_id' => $product->id,
    'label_id' => $label->id,
  ]);
 }
```

The problem that the query is working fine! I've tested it using insertGetId and it gives me the id of the row inserted, but nothing added to the database!

The strange thing, that this code is working fine when I use it in web.php for example, but what I've noticed in my database ( MySQL ) that the ids are not created in a numbered way, the ones that are missing are the same of the rows that I've tried to create using the query in the observer!

Here my migration file:

```
Schema::create('products_labels', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->bigInteger("product_id");
  $table->unsignedBigInteger("label_id");
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

I tried also using the Eloquent attach method and it's not working.

Another something strange happening is if I change the `$product->id` in the query by a value instead of a variable it works!

Comment: It's probably due to `$table->bigInteger("product_id");` not being unsigned, like how you have `$table->unsignedBigInteger("label_id");` defined.

Comment: also since you follow most of Laravel conventions you should name the table "label_product" instead, then you can omit the table name in belongsToMany relationship.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter  it already was unsigned big integer but the same problem

Comment: @AnuratChapanond can this cause the problem? i'll try it anyway thank you.

Comment: no, it's just a good practice to follow the convention but it shouldn't break anything if not followed.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll use it